# Client http request to open specific page issue

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make a http request and open a specific page in the browser. I've tried several packages such as npm opn, npm open, openurl but I can't get the desired objective. Here's what i'm trying:

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/index.html', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.html" );
})

app.post('/process_post', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {

   response = {
      fname:req.body.fname,
      surname:req.body.surname,
      age:req.body.age,
      phone:req.body.phone,
      city:req.body.phone,
      email:req.body.email,
      country:req.body.country,
      postal_code:req.body.postal_code,
      password:req.body.password
   };
   console.log(response);
   res.end(JSON.stringify(response));

   var exportJson= JSON.stringify(response);

   fs.writeFile("input.txt", exportJson, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
});

}) 

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port

   console.log("Listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```

client.js

```
var http = require('http');
var opn=require('opn');

// Options to be used by request 
var options = {
   host: '127.0.0.1',
   port: '8081',
   path: '/index.html'  
};

//opn("https://google.pt");
 var callback = function(response){
   // Continuously update stream with data
   var body = '';
   response.on('data', function(data) {
      body += data;
   });

   response.on('end', function() {
      console.log(body);
   });
}
var req = http.request(options, callback);
req.end();
```

EDIT:

I need to open the browser (the page is a form) through the client file which is connected to the server/localhost. Opening with npms like opn just opens the document, like:

```
opn(__dirname + "/" + "index.html"); //this line in the client.js
```

I wanted something like this:

```
var req = http.request(options, callback);
opn(options.path);//with this line, when running the client.js (with the server on), the program opens another command prompt...
req.end();
```

Comment: Why do you make request if you need to open browser?

Comment: can't i make the request and based on that request open the browser?

Comment: why do you need to do it? If you want to open `/index.html` just use `opn`. Or what do you want to get. Please make yourself clear

Comment: With this code, adding the line you suggested, other console (cmd) gets open. And with the answer Shigehiro Kamisama suggested i get in the client console "found. Redirecting to index.html", but the browser won't open. I'm tryng this because I want to make tests

Comment: `opn(options.path);`  doesn't work because you should call `opn` with full path i.e. `opn('http://127.0.0.1:8081/index.html')`

Comment: this worked Vladimir G. If you want to post an answer, you'll have the credit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`opn(options.path);` doesn't work because you should call `opn` with full path i.e. `opn('http://127.0.0.1:8081/index.html')`

Answer (score 1):

You want redirect to another page ? I don't really understand what you want to make.

You can use : `res.redirect('example.com');`

http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.redirect

EDIT :
Oh ok, i think i have understand, you want to open the browser with node.js in your console, it's this ?

EDIT 2 : 
Use [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

```
var req = http.request(options, callback);
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('explorer 127.0.0.1:8081'+options.path, (error, stdout, stderr) => { 
  if (error) return console.error(error : ${error})
})
req.end();
```

Try with this.

Comment: yes, your previous answer just gets me redirected console:("found. Redirecting to index.html")...I need to open the page in the browser through the app - connection client-server

Comment: Test with Child-process

Comment: I think you can run a cmd command with child_process for open your browser

Comment: with your edit: var req = http.request(options, callback);
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('explorer' + options.path, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) return console.error(`error : ${error}`)
});
req.end();

like this, the program opens my documents folder...I dont get it, weird...

Comment: I have edited my code a new time, try with this now, i think this can work.
With your code you trying to open a local file so you need to load it like a website, then use 127.0.0.1:8081

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but it's not working, i get similar results: i can read the whole html document in the console, but...no browser...:(

Comment: see the comment of Vladimir G. His solution worked. Just simple as this: var req = http.request(options, callback);
opn('http://127.0.0.1:8081/index.html');
req.end();

Comment: Oh, yes, i never used opn, just replace `/index.html` by your `options.path` value.